# Cursor going out of bound

Tags: android

I have a scenerio in which i have to move the cursor to next and previous. I am runing into exception when the cursor is already at the first or last location, then it throws out of bound exception.

How to tackle this situation ? What is the best way to handle it and currently i am handling it with exception [try and catch].

```
 public boolean nextWord()
   {
 boolean isVald = false;
 try
 {
    isVald = currentCursor.moveToNext();
    fillCurrentWord();

 } catch (Exception e)
 {
    Log.e("nextWord", e.toString());
 }

 return isVald;
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (!currentCursor.isLast()){
    currentCursor.moveToNext();
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can verify your current position using one of the following methods: `isFirst()`, `isBeforeFirst()`, `isLast()` or `isAfterLast()`